# discord.py can not embed image from local file

Tags: discord, discord.py

I embed a image using this code, it doesn't throw any error and it send a embed but nothing is there in the embed.

```py
e=discord.Embed()
file = discord.File("OWO.jpg", filename="OWO.jpg")
e.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://OWO.jpg")
msg = ctx.send(embed=e)
```

This is [my embed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKWKW.jpg) look like, There's nothing in it.

Answer (score 2):

## How do I use a local image file for an embed image?

Discord special-cases uploading an image attachment and using it within an embed so that it will not display separately, but instead in the embed’s thumbnail, image, footer or author icon.

To do so, upload the image normally with abc.Messageable.send(), and set the embed’s image URL to attachment://image.png, where image.png is the filename of the image you will send.

Quick example:

```py
file = discord.File("path/to/my/image.png", filename="image.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

> Note: Due to a Discord limitation, filenames may not include underscores.

Is there an event for audit log entries being created?

docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image

Answer (score 0):

You also need to send the file

```py
msg = await ctx.send(embed=e, file=file)
```

Comment: i went to send the file in the embed

Comment: I know, have you tried the code? It does exactly what you want

Comment: @cutebear Yes, you can use [await edit()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit%20message#discord.Message.edit).

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I'm a bit late to the party, but since cutebear didn't elaborate: This does not do what you claim it does. This sends the pic separate from the embed in the same message. That's not the same as having the pic in the embed.

Comment: @Opifex Yes, it does. It sends it as an image *in the embed*.

Comment: ŁukaszKwieciński No buddy. It doesn't. It sends it as part of the regular message, with the embed part underneath. @Delta's answer is the correct one here.

Comment: What's the difference between his and mine? Apart from tha part where I didn't copy OPs code (cause it's correct, no need to change something that's correct), just added to it.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński again: yours sends a picture AND an embed. Instead of sending a picture IN an embed. It's a very different outcome.