# How do I use my own images in my local machine for discord.py bot embeds?

Tags: discord.py

I want to use images in my local machine for my bot. But so far I have only heard that it accepts URLs from a website, for example. How do I use my own images? If I understand it correctly,  the API uses the URLs to go the site and pick the image. I'm not sure about that. If there's a way to do it, can anyone tell?

**Example as to what I mean:**

```
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    . . .
    embed.set_image(<directory to the file location>)
    . . .
```

I'm pretty sure this is not possible by how the API makes embeds, but please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image

Comment: I don't think you can. You can try uploading your image to a public hosting site and take the url.

Comment: Apparently you can @Soumya, as per the previous message. Anyways, thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
embed = discord.Embed()
file = discord.File("path/to/my/image.png", filename="image.png")
embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

[Similar question/source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68942255/discord-py-can-not-embed-image-from-local-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a picture from a api then do this. I'm use sra in this example

AIOhttp:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get("https://some-random-api.ml/animal/dog") as resp:
        response = resp.json()
        image = response["image"] #its a url
await ctx.send(image)
```

To download an image from a web say its not a url or json type:
Read: [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)